# Music Streaming Service

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, server, stream

I've got a client-side written in React. Also, on my Google Drive I've got some music. I want to make a music streaming service and play my music online and non-stop from my Google Drive. I'm noob in server-side programming. What do you recommend me to read or do to write such radio?

Comment: What issue are you currently having playing media?

Comment: @guest271314, don't know how to get music from my google-drive and render it to my player

Comment: How do you currently listen to the music?

Comment: @guest271314, my player is hollow right now. I want it to get music from GD and play ;)

Comment: _"I want it to get music from GD and play"_ Do you currently listen to music at the application that you are referencing? Can you provide a link to one or more of the audio files at the application?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 I basicly don't know how to do that, I'm noob. Just need an algorithm or hint. What technology to use, how to request for files in GD, etc.

Comment: You can use `HTMLMediaElement` `<audio>`, and JavaScript to repeatly schedule media playback of a media playlist of paths pointing to valid media files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `<audio>` element to playback audio media. One approach to loop media playback would be to create an array containing path to media resources within an object.

At `canplay` event of `<audio>` element call `.play()`. At `ended` event return a resolved `Promise`.

Pass the array to `.reduce()` initialized with a resolved `Promise`. Use `.then()` to call function again when all media tracks have played.

You can also use a `Boolean` flag to stop repeated scheduling of call to same function which loops media playback of requested media resources.

```js
const mediaPlaylist = [{
  "track": "https://doc-0c-48-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/dhtqfqf4pt2b3kmukb3m1bcqjcsgcu8o/1499925600000/15486589845087228196/*/0B30WhR3Lbl-cQ3NFRzBuVk5KN28",
  "title": "Hypnotize U"
}, {
  "track": "https://doc-08-48-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/1fk2t6ot905rc6fs7ifil1sag5vr5h22/1499925600000/15486589845087228196/*/0B30WhR3Lbl-cR2JEQ3VvT0dxYzQ?e=download",
  "title": "Rock Star"
}, {
  "track": "https://doc-0c-48-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/rmop35nhocd25kroorov3p336f15i9m5/1499925600000/15486589845087228196/*/0B30WhR3Lbl-cU2lsdjVpMTRUcGM?e=download",
  "title": "She Want To Move"
}];

const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

const nowPlaying = audio.nextElementSibling;

const mediaTracks = ((promise, {
    track,
    title
  }) =>
  promise.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
    audio.src = track;
    audio.addEventListener("canplay", event => {
      audio.play();
      nowPlaying.textContent = title;
    }, {
      once: true
    });
    audio.addEventListener("ended", event => {
      nowPlaying.textContent = "";
      resolve();
    }, {
      once: true
    });
  }))
);

let stopMedia = false;

const mediaLoop = (playlist = Array()) =>
  !stopMedia 
  ? playlist.reduce(mediaTracks, Promise.resolve()) 
  : Promise.resolve("media loop stopped");

const playMedia = () => 
mediaLoop(mediaPlaylist).then(playMedia);

playMedia()
.then(message => console.log(message))
.catch(err => {console.log(err); throw err});
```

```html
<audio controls></audio>Now playing: <label></label>
```

Comment: How did you get those links from GD?

Comment: @ИльяРаецкий Following the link that you provided at now deleted comment

Comment: I have used this links in my React Component by I got a 403 error
Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/nw0askhc/

Comment: Also, I got this error #DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.#

Comment: @ИльяРаецкий Noticed that the URL was no longer loading resource as well. Apparently GD did not approve of the URL being requested? Why did you remove link to media files?